# SSH Server Supports Weak MAC Algorithms

Tags: ssh

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.9, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

Ciphers and MACs are not configured in ubuntu server/etc/ssh/sshd_config. Why is there this risk?

The SSH server software running on the host is configured to support weak MAC algorithms. These should be disabled to ensure that your server stays secure as attacks evolve.

Is it possible or recommended to Disable support for any weak MAC algorithms on your SSH server

Comment: Your provided details that imply you've not applied security fixes/upgrades since beginning of 2022 (*if not earlier*), so I'll suggest if security matters to you, you apply security fixes asap.  (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/02/25/ubuntu-20-04-4-lts-released/ shows the release date of 20.04.4 but installed systems upgraded to that before that date, and a fully upgraded system now reports as [20.04.6](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/))